# EF Core did not change entity to unmodified

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I would like to change my TransferedAt property besides leaving the ModifiedAt property unchanged. So I don't want the ChangeTracker to recognized modification of TransferedAt as real entity changes. Because I need the ModifiedAt property for other purpose.
But this code does nothing.

```
 var entityEntry = _context.Entry(document);
 entityEntry.Property(x => x.TransferedAt).IsModified = false;
 document.TransferedAt = now;
```

My ChangeTracker:

```
foreach (var ent in this.ChangeTracker.Entries()
            .Where(p => p.State == EntityState.Added
            || p.State == EntityState.Modified
            || p.State == EntityState.Deleted))
        {
            if (ent.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                ((ICreated)ent.Entity).CreatedAt = now;
            }
            else if (ent.State == EntityState.Modified )
            {
                ((IModified)ent.Entity).ModifiedAt = now;
            }
            else if (ent.State == EntityState.Deleted)
            {
                ((IDeleted)ent.Entity).DeletedAt = now;
                ent.State = EntityState.Modified; //Soft delete
            }
        }
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

detach the entity from the context before making the modification!

check this out :

```
var entityEntry = _context.Entry(document);
entityEntry.State = EntityState.Detached;

document.TransferedAt = now;

//reattach the entity to the context
_context.Attach(document);

//exclude TransferedAt from being recognized as a modified property
entityEntry.Property(x => x.TransferedAt).IsModified = false;

//and save changes to persist the modified TransferedAt property
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: TransferedAt remains null.

Comment: @JaczuraZoltán so verify that the `document` object is correctly retrieved from the context and is not null before making modifications, you can add a null check to ensure the object is valid and check if there are any validation rules or constraints in your database schema that prevent the `TransferedAt` property from being updated!

Comment: The document is not null, and when earlier I only used document.TransferedAt = now; it worked perfect.

Comment: Please kindly consider selecting my solution as the chosen answer if it resolves your issue, and also, if you found it helpful, you can press `^` button as well!